# In tmux 2.6+ how do you start tmux with a set number of tabs named without creating a bash script and only using .tmux.conf file

Tags: tmux

Many of the tmux solutions to creating a bunch of tabs open on tmux start requires a bash script. Is there a method where you can just do this in the .tmux.conf file?

I have a bunch of servers to connect to on tmux and I like to name them in my tabs. I also don't want to install additional tmux software like resurrect as I want it as bare bones tmux as possible and do everything in .tmux.conf if possible.

Also would I be able to define splits in tmux.conf too ?

Comment: Er, tabs is non-standard tmux terminology. Sessions? Windows? Panes? Note that many tmux keyboard shortucts have equivalent programmatic commands (man tmux) which you can use anywhere.

Comment: the tabs on the bottom of the tmux console. maybe i mean windows...

Comment: See https://leanpub.com/the-tao-of-tmux/read#thinking-tmux (these are windows)

Answer (score 1):

In short, see `man tmux` and add commands like

```
new-window
```

to your configuration